# Microsoft Excel. How to put all tables from all lists to a single list

Tags: excel, datatables, ms-office

Is it possible somehow to do the following in Microsoft Excel?
Every list has a single table with its own Header:

[image]

Table may be of any size, and number of such lists is unknown in advance.

I need to gather all those tables in the very first list which is called "Main" so that each table just followed by another like this:

[image]

I need it only for printing, so sorting and another stuff like this is unnecessary.
Microsoft Excel - 2019.

Comment: Have added another edit at bottom of my answer - thought over what you said some more...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you are after using *named ranges* [per this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRnyhjeMHfs).

The ranges are then accessible from the dropdown to the left of the formula bar.

I find it easy to select area of tables first, then define a named range based on currently selected area, rather than entering it in the prompt per the video.
  1. **Insert -> Name -> Define Name**

If you have a workbook with multiple sheets you can define names on any sheet, So lets's say table1 was in sheet1, and table2 in sheet2. If sheet1 was the active sheet, you could still select the named range of table2, and Excel will automatically flip sheets for you and select that area as if you had just highlighted the region.

Later when it comes to printing, select the named area, and the say
 
  2. **File -> Print Area -> Set Print Area**

Then do:
 
  3. **Print** and instead of selecting <strike>Active Sheet</strike> use **Selection**

(I am talking about doing it on a Mac V16.22 - but should be similar on Windows too)

**EDIT:**

There is **IMPORTRANGE** in Google Sheets.

Not sure if something similar in Excel was what you were after.

So take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1187444/equivalent-of-google-sheets-importrange%20-) too.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it seems that it is not exactly what I would like to do. This xls file should be a kind of template. Anybody should be able to open it and just create a new page with table. All other actions Excel should do by itself (put all tables one by one on the first page). People who will be working with Excel are not familiar with it, they are newbies, so they can't do all of steps you described...

Comment: Really? What you are suggesting is far more work! The only other way would be to use VBA. Every table would have to have it's own address range manually added to the script. Far more technical than this.

Comment: Have not used those.

Comment: Have just had a cursory Google of that. If it's what I think it is... May be good to look at something like Tableau..

Comment: You know each table you add as a defined name starts building a list. So you can select any one from a list after.